# Create table from union of two CTE

Tags: amazon-redshift

How can we create a table from the following query that unions 2 CTEs?

```
with a as (.....),
b as (.....)
Select *
FROM a
UNION
SELECT *
FROM b
```

Comment: As long as the datatypes on the fields line up this should work fine...  are you getting an error?  Prefix with `create table foo as`.

Comment: Thanks, Hambone.  I had tried that earlier and got an error but now it works.